# Doctrine: get more context on scheme reverse engineering type mapping

Tags: php, mysql, enums, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to develop a MySQL enum type that uses PHP 8 enums, in order to replace a good old:

```
#[ORM\Column(type: Types::STRING, length: 16, enumType: Language::class)]
```

By:

```
#[ORM\Column(type: 'enum', enumType: Language::class)]
```

And moreover, prevent that someone inserts a wrong value that would break objects hydratation.

---

For this, I created a custom doctrine type:

```
<?php

namespace App\Doctrine\DBAL\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;

class EnumType extends Type
{
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        $enumType = $fieldDeclaration['enumType'] ?? null;

        // Because Doctrine uses ::from() method coming from \BackedEnum contract when hydrating objects
        if (!\is_subclass_of($enumType, \BackedEnum::class)) {
            throw new \LogicException('Doctrine "enum" type requires a native PHP 8 backed enum class in the "enumType" column mapping property.');
        }

        // TODO escape values containing quotes

        return \sprintf(
            'ENUM(%s)',
            \implode(',', \array_map(fn($e) => \sprintf("'%s'", $e->value), $enumType::cases()))
        );
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return 'enum';
    }

    public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When running a first doctrine migration, I properly get the expected enumeration:

```
public function up(Schema $schema): void
{
    // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE user_preference CHANGE language language ENUM(\'fr\',\'en\') NOT NULL COMMENT \'(DC2Type:enum)\'');
}
```

But once the MySQL scheme contains that enum(), Doctrine cannot perform any diffs anymore.

The first error is quite obvious, Doctrine is not aware of the `enum` type:

> Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it.

So I added its support in my custom type:

```
public function getMappedDatabaseTypes(AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return ['enum'];
}
```

But when `getSQLDeclaration` is called from my class, it does not contain enough context:

```
^ array:12 [
  "name" => "language"
  "type" => App\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\EnumType^ {#569}
  "default" => null
  "notnull" => true
  "length" => 0
  "precision" => 10
  "scale" => 0
  "fixed" => false
  "unsigned" => false
  "autoincrement" => false
  "comment" => "(DC2Type:enum)"
  "version" => false
]
```

As you can see, the mysql `enum()` values (what's inside the braces) are not provided, so I"m not able to reconstruct the same SQL declaration.

Is there a way to get more context? Or add a custom comment containing the values?